# typescript error cannot-invoke-an-object-which-is-possibly-undefined after optional send 2 props function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to make Form re-use component By something like this

```
<Form onEdit={onEdit}} />
<Form onAdd={onAdd}} />
```

In my Form

```
const FormTodo = ({ onAdd, onEdit,}: FormProps) => {}
```

I want to do something like this

```
export interface FormProps {
  onAdd?: (data: string) => void;
  onEdit?: (someText: string) => void;
}
```

the problem is ? (optional) it's not allow me to put flag

Comment: What do you mean by "put flag"? That you can't call ```onAdd()``` because it is possibly undefined?

Comment: It sounds like you need to check whether the function exists before calling it. E.g. `if (typeof onAdd === "function") onAdd(...)`. If at least one of onAdd or onEdit are required then you can use a union type to indicate this `type Props = { onAdd: (data: string) => void } | { onEdit: (someText: string) => void`.